# Vue 3 composition api computed property = template not updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a computed property but it is not working

I can see that `currentMode` is changing with the console.log

but my template is not updating

template:
`<div v-if="editMode"></div>`

setup:

```
setup(props, context) {

let currentMode = null
const modes = {
   view:'view',
   edit:'edit',
   create:'create'
}
const editMode = computed(() => {
   return currentMode === modes.edit
});

const toggleMode = () => {
  if (currentMode === modes.edit ){
    currentMode = modes.view
    console.log(currentMode)
    return
  }  else {
    currentMode = modes.edit
    console.log(currentMode)
  }
}

return {editMode, toggleMode}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make modes reactive

```
let currentMode = ref(null)
const modes = ref({
  view:'view',
  edit:'edit',
  create:'create'
})
const editMode = computed(() => {
  return currentMode.value === modes.value.edit
});

const toggleMode = () => {
  if (currentMode.value === modes.value.edit ){
    currentMode.value = modes.value.view
    console.log(currentMode.value)
    return
  }  else {
    currentMode.value = modes.value.edit
    console.log(currentMode.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that, sorry I made a mistake with parenthesis

Comment: I added ref like suggested but no luck with that either

Comment: with `ref()` added my `toggleMode` function does not work anymore

Comment: it fails at `currentMode.value = modes.value.edit` says attempted to assign to read only property

Comment: thanks for double checking, yes I have let

Comment: You are welcome mate, cheers :) pls upvote if you like .)